# Arduino array length

Tags: arduino-uno

So I have a programme that loads a text file from an sd card into a string array. Each line in the text file is stored in a different string in a string array. Well its supposed to be.

```
file = SD.open("/classes/basic.txt", FILE_READ);
Serial.print("Reading, Checking and Compiling \n\n\n");  

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(result)-1;i++){
 while(file.available()) {
  character23 = file.read();
  content.concat(character23); 

}    
if (content != "") {     
  result[i] = content;
    Serial.println(content);

}
```

}

I want each line in the txt file to be stored in a different string in the array, in chronological order and each string has to be accessible individually. The problem with this code is that it stores the whole text file in one string. How can I fix this?

EDIT: here is what I have now

```
  file = SD.open("/classes/basic.txt", FILE_READ);
  Serial.print("Reading, Checking and Compiling \n\n\n");  

 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(result)-1;i++){
   while(file.available()) {
  character23 = file.read();
  if (character23 == '^') break;
  content.concat(character23); 

}    
if (content != "") {     
  result[i] = content;
  Serial.println(content);

  delay(1000);
}
```

}
 Serial.println(result[3]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to read the file until you reach a line break.

Replace this code:

```
while(file.available()) {
  character23 = file.read();
  content.concat(character23);
}
```

by this:

```
while(file.available()) {
   character23 = file.read();
   if (character23 == '\n') break;
   content.concat(character23);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to debug and I'm trying to find what is stored in a certain string of the array is this correct: Serial.println(result[1]); because it keeps returning nothing

Comment: Can you show your complete code rather than a snippet?

Comment: ye ill edit the above code

Comment: where is the declaration of the array? Also, this line is wrong `if (character23 == '^') break;`. It should be `\n` not `^`.

Comment: ye but all the lines in the txt file end in ^

Comment: The array is at the top of the class

Comment: string Array[4];

Comment: what if you print the first line? like this: Serial.println(result[0]);

Comment: it prints nothing

Comment: if I rpint content I get

Comment: println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)
println("sharkByte OS v1.1)
delay(2000)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35826/discussion-between-kira-san-and-user2279603).